# Bounding expected maximum of inner products

Tags: probability, optimization, random-variable, probability-inequalities

Let  $x=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})^{T}$ be $n$ dimensional random vector uniformly distributed over the $L1$ unit sphere. That is, all $x$ such that $\|x\|_{1} = 1$ have equal probability and all other $x$ have zero.

Let $\{c_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be $n$ vectors such that $\|c_{i}\|_{2}=1$.

How can one show that:

$\mathbb{E}_{x}\{\max_{j\in[n]}|\langle c_{j},x\rangle|\} \leq \mathbb{E}_{x}\{\|x\|_{\infty}\}$

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the meaning of "ball" as being all vectors of norm *less than or equal to* $1$ rather than equal to $1$. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @whuber - I meant equality, the boundary points only

Comment: Just to establish a connection with this site, let me remark that this question can be viewed as a $2^n$-means clustering problem for data that are uniformly distributed on the boundary of a "hyper-octahedron" (a square in 2D, an octahedron in 3D, etc.).  It asks us to show that there is no $2^n$-means solution that is any better than the one that places the $2^n$ cluster centers at each of the $2^n$ vertices of the hyperoctahedron.  (This is intuitively clear but still requires a rigorous proof, which I find elusive.)